# Java 1.8 method CriteriaBuilder between is not applicable (Netbeans 8.2)

Tags: java

I have a problem with CriteriaBuilder in my project. 
I get the error:

> method CriteriaBuilder between is not applicable

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: you probably have a missing dependency.

Comment: no, I have only problem with between. For example: cb.literal is ok

Comment: cb.literal is not giving error because an error has already been shown at cb.between.

Comment: Unfortunately, but I don't agree with Karan Verma. I have cb.literal in other function and works fine. It's strange but in Netbeans 8.0.2 I don't have this problem.

Comment: maybe cb.literal doesn't of the same type (Date) of Path (first parameter)